# Difference between a blank cell and a cell with value =""

Tags: excel

Given a new blank excel worksheet, suppose I write ="" on cell A2.
On cell A3, I write =IF(A1=A2, 1, 0). It will return 1.

Now, I write =TEXT(A1, "000000") on cell A4 and =TEXT(A2, "000000") on cell A5.
Cell A4 will read 000000, while cell A5 is blank.

Now, I understand that the difference comes from the fact that I set A2 to be "". However, A3 tells me that they are the same in value. How do you explain what is the difference between them? Moreover, how would you make =TEXT(A2, "000000") return 000000 when A2 = ""?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A1` is "blank," and you can detect this using the `ISBLANK` function.  `=ISBLANK(A1)` returns true, whereas `=ISBLANK(A2)` returns false.

I'm not an expert on Excel internals, but everything I've seen is consistent with the idea that a blank cell gets coerced to the empty string "" in contexts where you're using it as a string, and gets coerced to 0 in contexts where you're using it as a number.  So in the case where you compare a blank cell to "", the blank cell is regarded as the empty string and therefore matches.  When you format the blank cell as a number, it gets interpreted as zero and handled accordingly, but when you try to interpret the blank *string* as a *number* it doesn't work.

To get something that interprets "" as zero, you're probably going to have to write something like

```
=TEXT(IF(A2="", 0, A2), "000000")
```